# Cloning After Knockout Update

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Any ideas why this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karl1coleman/vrnaw2at/2/) doesn't work? What I'm trying to do is see if I can use an HTML node as a template that updates with Knockout. The initial clone works but when I update the model and then try to clone again, the previous value is still in the resulting HTML. I put the timeout in to make sure it wasn't a timing issue with knockout having to update everything before I called clone(), but it didn't make a difference.

```
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<div>
    <div id="template" >
        <label>Description</label>
        <label data-bind="text: descr"></label>
    </div>
</div>

var model = {
    descr: ko.observable('Karl')   
}
ko.applyBindings(model);
var $dom = $('#template').clone();
$('h1').append($dom);
model.descr('Keith');
setTimeout(function() {
    var $dom1 = $('#template').clone();
    $('h2').append($dom1);
}, 3000);
```

UPDATE:
The problem was obvious once I looked at it with a fresh head this morning. After I clone and insert, my DOM has two elements with the id 'template'. When I try to clone it the second time, since I inserted it prior to the original, it grabs it first. I don't know knockout's internal workings, but even through it has the data-bind attribute, knockout isn't updating it, only the original. So what I needed to do was give the clone a new id. I updated the JSFiddle with the working code.

Comment: I think it's because every clone is bound to `var model`. I'll see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The `ko.applyBindings(model)` call is happening immediately and is only applied to the currently available elements.

Any subsequent markup that is added to the page with a data-bind attribute will not work unless `applyBindings` is called again for only those new elements.

At least thats the way I see it... but interestingly enough the below change to your code.. seems to work for both of your clones... not just 1 of them.

```
var model = {
    descr: ko.observable('Karl')   
}

var $dom = $('#template').clone();

$('h1').append($dom);

// move this below the clone and .append calls
ko.applyBindings(model);

model.descr('Keith');

setTimeout(function() {
    var $dom1 = $('#template').clone();
    $('h2').append($dom1);
}, 3000);
```

You can't just `applyBindings` again because its invalid to apply a binding to an element twice.

The way to achieve this properly is to specify the element you are applying the binding to.

i.e.

`ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementByID("my element id here"));`

and then any further dynamic markup or async partially loaded markup should have the binding for your view model applied on just that element in a callback method.